# multiplying 3d and 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d array of shape `(3, 4, 3)` and a 2d array of shape `(3, 3)`. I am trying to multiply them such that the `i`th element of the 3d result is the `i`th element of `x` (shape `3, 3)`) multiplied by the `i`th element of `y` (shape `(3,)`). Is there a way to replicate this without a for loop?

```
x = np.arange(36).reshape((3,4,3))
y = np.arange(9). reshape(3,3)

l = []
for xs, ys in zip(x, y):
    l.append(xs * ys)
    
print(np.array(l))
```

I tried using * and dot, and they don't work

Comment: What is "this"? What are you trying to accomplish? A verbal description with the code will help us understand your question better.

Comment: Most numpy operations have an `axis` value. It dictates how elementwise operations should behave.

Comment: Why `dot`?  Are you doing matrix multiplication, the kind of thing you did in high school on matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape your `y` to `(3, 1, 3)` and then multiply it with `x`:

```
l2 = x * y.reshape((3, 1, 3))
print((l2 == l).all()) # True
```

Alternatively, use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to specify that you want to multiply the first axis of `x` with the first axis of `y`, and the last axis of `x` with the last axis of `y`:

```
l3 = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ijk', x, y)
print((l3 == l).all()) # True
```